# How to slice PSD template to html/css?

Tags: html, css, templates, psd

I'm coding a PSD template into html/css. The file consists of about 50 layers, which I have exported to PNG with a Photoshop script.
I started like this:

```
<div id="container_1">
  <div id="container_2">
    <div id="containter_3">
       etc
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Each layer is exactly the template size, with transparent background. At first I was happy with this approach, as it worked all right and allowed me not to worry about positioning much, but as the number of divs is now enormous, the code starts looking weird to me, not to mention the page loads really slowly now.
This must be a really stupid question to ask, but should I have cropped the images after exporting them from the PSD? Maybe even combine several layers together instead of putting them on the page separately one over another (there are several layers that create a decorative border around blocks with text)?

Comment: Without trying to sound too nasty the approach you have taken to doing this is called insanity. I'd advise going to college/university and taking a course in web design and development.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could give this tutorial a try: http://net.tutsplus.com/articles/news/slice-and-dice-that-psd/